# Guarantee a returned array's length

Tags: java, arrays

I want to attempt to assign a "contract" or some type of basis to a method that will guarantee that the length of an array returned from a method will always have `x` length.

In pseudo-java, this would be amazing:

```
public String[4] someMethod() {...}
```

However, that seems to not be syntactically correct. My thought from there was to create an `@interface` to guarantee this:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ArrayLength {

    public int size() default 0;

}

//...
@ArrayLength(size = 4)
public String[] someMethod() {...}
```

But this is really only a superficial fix at the moment. Is there a way to either generate a simple method of guaranteeing an array length (without running through exceptions) that may through compiler / IDE warnings, or is this not currently possible in java?

As a bonus, if there's a way to simply generate a warning through netbeans (my IDE) and then remove the excess on compile-time, that would be wonderful.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why/how do you know that your array will always have exactly 4 elements?

Comment: In the example above, it would be for that particular method that the array returned would represent a data of some type (a "format" for data if you will).

Comment: Any reason not to just create a class for the return type that is a fixed array of size 4?

Comment: Well yes, I suppose creating a class would be another solution (wouldn't even need an array in that sense). That's more logical now that I think about it.

As far as what the question originally addressed, it was more or less to show that "This array is guarunteed to have `x` length, thus  you do not need to verify the length of the contents"

Comment: Yeah, it does seem a little like overkill to create a new class to just wrap a String array of length 4, but unfortunately that's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: There's not really any way to do this, other than using some sort of wrapper class.

Comment: Using a new class is likely the correct solution. If those 4 String elements represent some domain concept then a new class is definitely the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.project.stock.testArray;

public interface ILen {
    String GET_ARRAY = "getArray";

    public String[] getArray(String arr[]);

}

package com.project.stock.testArray;

/**
 * @author Bhaskar
 */
public class ComputeLength implements ILen {

    /*
     * Desciption: Method checks for the length of the input array and returns
     * it.
     * 
     * @see com.project.stock.testArray.ILen#getArray(java.lang.String[])
     */
    public String[] getArray(String arr[]) {
        // Returns if the input array is of length 4.
        if (arr.length == 4) {
            for (String str : arr) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            return arr;
        }
        // Returns if the input array is of length greater than 4 and checks if
        // each for string.
        else if (arr.length > 4) {
            String[] arr_copy = new String[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                if (i >= 4) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (arr[i].matches("[a-zA-Z]*")) {
                        arr_copy[i] = arr[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            for (String str : arr_copy) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            return arr_copy;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Length" + arr.length);
            String[] arr_duplicate;
            arr_duplicate = arr.clone();
            for (String str : arr_duplicate) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            return arr_duplicate;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComputeLength obj = new ComputeLength();
        String arr[] = new String[10];
        arr[0] = "Name";
        arr[1] = "Address";
        arr[2] = "City";
        arr[3] = "Country";
        obj.getArray(arr);
    }
}
```

Hope this could be of some help for you.

What I could extract from what you have mentioned is, that you need a method which returns you a string of length 4 with all sorts of input. I have tried to design the same with mock objects. The code considers that the string can be of any length and returns first four values from the input array in-case input array exceeds the length of 4. 
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is "contractual length", or guaranteeing the length outside the scope of the method. Think of it like "This method is guaranteed to return an object of Type `x`", but also including length. Of course I can solve that in my own code, but it's less... safe I want to say. Using a class object made more sense in the end.